# Store some login information to be used throughout the application

Tags: reactjs, redux, store

I'm looking for a way to store some information captured on login. This information will be used to make calls to a database later. Is this the User case for Redux? I dont need to store functions but store UID string along with another identifier.

Looking for some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to store it even user closes the website and reuses it again, use localStorage or session-storage or cookies.

We you want to keep it in an application then use context API provided by react itself.
keeping such small info (only login info no other thing) in redux would an overkill.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was thinking but just wanted to confirm.